# SceneBuilder 2.0 Dynamic shape generation

Tags: java, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I have an FXML file that does some certain animations with some right now static(so to speak) shapes that are hard-coded into the fxml.  What I am trying to do is dynamically create shapes from Java Objects that have certain properties such as color which these objects will be pulling from a database and populate the fxml with these object based shapes, I am not sure how to go about doing this.  Below is the code for the main class, I know why the error is happening but not sure how to do it any other way.

```
public class TestConveyorView extends GuiceApplication {

  @Inject
  private GuiceFXMLLoader fxmlLoader;

  public Injector createInjector() {
      return Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
          @Override
          protected void configure() {
          }
      });
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void init(List<Module> modules) throws Exception {
}

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
      //GridPane root = new GridPane();
     Parent root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fxml/TestConveyorView.fxml")).getRoot();

     Box box = new Box(1, red);
     Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(50,50,box.getColor());
     // Can't seem to add it to the scene, problem occurs here.
     root.getChildren().add(rectangle);


     Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    // BackgroundImage background = new BackgroundImage(null, BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT, BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }



}
```

Comment: do you have any code you've written where we can help you with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed the problem by changing

```
Parent root = ...
```

To

```
AnchorPane root = ...
```

Simple fix that I overlooked I guess.